# Can't install Laravel4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I try to install Laravel4 on windows 8.

I download the file, unzip it, and call "composer update"
then i have these messages :

```
    PHP Warning:  require(D:\sites\lara\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\sites\lara\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() D:\sites\lara\artisan:0
PHP   2. require() D:\sites\lara\artisan:16
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'D:\sites\lara\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\sites\lara\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() D:\sites\lara\artisan:0
PHP   2. require() D:\sites\lara\artisan:16

Warning: require(D:\sites\lara\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\sites\lara\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Call Stack:
    0.0002     231464   1. {main}() D:\sites\lara\artisan:0
    0.0005     236592   2. require('D:\sites\lara\bootstrap\autoload.php') D:\sites\lara\artisan:16


Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\sites\lara\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\sites\lara\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Call Stack:
    0.0002     231464   1. {main}() D:\sites\lara\artisan:0
    0.0005     236592   2. require('D:\sites\lara\bootstrap\autoload.php') D:\sites\lara\artisan:16

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Warning:  require(D:\sites\lara\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\sites\lara\boo
  tstrap\autoload.php on line 17
  PHP Stack trace:
  PHP   1. {main}() D:\sites\lara\artisan:0
  PHP   2. require() D:\sites\lara\artisan:16
  PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'D:\sites\lara\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\sites\lara\boot
  strap\autoload.php on line 17
  PHP Stack trace:
  PHP   1. {main}() D:\sites\lara\artisan:0
  PHP   2. require() D:\sites\lara\artisan:16




update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
[-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

If I try by typing composer create-project laravel/laravel

I have

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v4.0.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v4.0.0)
    Downloading: 100%
    Downloading: 100%
    Downloading: 100%



  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://nodeload.github.com/laravel/laravel/zip/v4.0.0" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl"
   - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [package] [directory] [version]
```

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jason Lewis is right. Just comment out the openssl extension in your php.ini, run the command again in cmd shall fix your problem. No need to restart your PC or server.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling `update`. You should first call `install`.

As for the `create-project` method, I also had the same problem. But it went away.

Please consult the documentation fully when attempting an install.

Comment: Yes my bad I call "composer install" and i read the doc but the "composer install" way was working with beta without any problem

Comment: I'd say you need to enable the `openssl` extension in your `PHP.ini` then restart Apache.

Comment: I see - sometimes people do start with an update, so I just had to make sure. @Jason: ah! Thanks for reminding me - I did it so quickly in my install, that I can't even remember doing it. That did indeed solve the issue when I had it. To my knowledge, some PHP installs have it pre-loaded. But not XAMPP or MAMP.

Comment: Yes thanx Jason. That's the solution. I am using WAMP and I enabled openSSL by the software, but I forgot to modify the php.ini for the CLI... Thanx Mike too :)